# Getting cursor information using imagesc

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using `imagesc` multiple times to plot some data on the same plot (figure).

At the end of those iterations I get the desired plot.
I wish to get the entire information available by the cursor:

[(see image here: plot and cursor info)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccg9w.png)

But I don't want to get the information about a specific location `(x,y)`, but to get a matrix containing all info: x,y,index, r, g, b - for every x,y.
That is, a `size(x) * size(y)  * 4` matrix containing the entire data.

Is that possible?

Comment: Wouldn't that be `size(x) * size(y) * 6`? (x, y, index, red, green, blue)?

Comment: Does this information come from *multiple* `imagesc` objects?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very close, but I'm still getting something wrong with the scaling of the colors... I'll have another look at it tonight.

```
% Create random image
m=rand(180);
im=imagesc(m);

% Extract indices
Index=im.CData';

% Get RGB colors
cm=colormap;
a = floor(Index'*length(cm));
RGB=permute(ind2rgb(uint16(a),cm),[2 1 3]);
```

This is just ever so slightly off from the actual RGB values, but the indexed values correspond to those of the figure. Note that I transposed the CData to get it fro ij mode to xy mode.